# Can't figure out specific layout constraints in xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

So after many head aches I've finally started understanding how to work with layout constraints in xcode 8 but simply cannot figure out how to get these 2 buttons to layout properly. [It's the 'faucet' and 'wallet' buttons I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB7Gl.png). Each button is half the width of the screen but will not scale correctly when I attempt to use the layout constraints.

Comment: Please describe the constraints you are setting. I would suggest an equal width constraint between the two buttons, an aspect ratio constraint of 1:2 between the width of one of the buttons and the width of the superview.  Finally constrain the leading edge of the left button to the leading edge of the superview. The trailing edge of that button to the leading edge of the first and the trailing edge of the second button to the trailing edge of the superview.

Answer (score 0):

First select both button and add constraint as like as image:

[image]

Comment: please add more explanation to your answer. ;)